# Is there any easy method to update media or page links inside a wordpress post or page after website migration

Tags: php, database, wordpress, database-migration, broken-links

I have a wordpress website, that i just completed customisation within my localhost. Where i set permlinks **`http://localhost/nwp`** as my siteurl and home url. And in my website i used links inside my pages and posts for referring images,videos and other pages and posts. When i migrate this website into my live server i changed  my site url and home url to **`http://mydomain.com`**. but the url i pasted inside pages and posts still exists as old like **`http://localhost/nwp/uploads/2014/img.jpg`** ,**`http://localhost/nwp/your-page`** etc.. I  can fix this issue by opening all pages or posts and replacing  those old links inside pages or posts with new links .But it take too much time. i didn't know any other method to solve this problem easily.Please help me If any one know a better method  to fix this issue easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your Answers. But I just found a secure and easy way without any help of additional download script. we need to execute sql `UPDATE` query to update all contents in database as below.

```
mysql> UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://localhost/nwp','http://mydomain.com');

mysql> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://localhost/nwp', 'http://mydomain.com');

mysql> UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://localhost/nwp','http://mydomain.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you exported your database you can open it with some editor like Notepad++ and just replace the strings.

As @RadGH mentioned it will be wise to use a serialized search and replace script. Is is safer. You can find it here: [DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: Note that if you replace content in a serialized string, you will (likely) corrupt the serialization and WordPress will discard the entire value. I HIGHLY reccomend using a serialized search and replace script instead (it does the same thing, only safer): https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: @RadGH Thanks for the info. Could you consider in adding your information as an answer? I will upvote it.

Comment: You can add my suggestion to your original answer if you'd like. They are very similar and it looks like Peter has already mentioned it separately anyway.

Comment: This is one awesome method but not a safer way at all.else we need to download additional script for this too.thanx for your answer